# Rails Associations - undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Basic question on Rails associations with the following tables:

- **Shop:** name, network
- **Product:** title, price, shop_id

Relation defined as **has_many** and **belongs_to**:

**Model:**

*shop.rb*

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
    has_many   :products
end
```

*product.rb*

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
     self.primary_key = "id"
     belongs_to :shop
end
```

Controller:


*shops_controller.rb*

```
  def show
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
 end
```

*products_controller.rb*

```
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end
```

In the **Shop view** I manage to reference and show all Products for each Shop without problems:

```
<%= @shop.name %>
<%= @shop.network %>

  <% @shop.products.each do |product| %>
   <%= product.title %>
  <% end %>
```

But the other way around in the **Product** view I don't manage to show the network information from the Shop table :

```
  <%= @product.title %>
  <%= @product.shop.network %>
```

This returns the following error:

```
undefined method `network' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Every product belongs to a shop, or are there somevwithout?

Comment: All products have one shop (referenced in the product table with shop_id)

Comment: have you checked whether shop_id is right and not null?

Comment: Thank you, sometimes the solution is so simple. That specific shop_id I tested was not in the shop table. So setup in general is correct. Thanks again, this took me a long time!

Comment: Unrelated to the already answered question: I would remove `self.primary_key = "id"` and just use RailsApi defaults. Also add a presence check if a product might nog have a shop (if it should always have a shop a presence check is redundant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user **jith** pointed out - the setup is correct and working. The problem was that one specific shop_id could not be found.

So make sure all _id's are in the other table when working with associations.

Thank you!